screen doesn't wake up after resume from suspend
I'm have installed Devuan Daedalus in my friend's computer. It is a HP laptop with AMD RYZEN 3 and Radeon Graphics.
As expected, all the function keys don't work. That is alright.
After suspend, when the system resumes, the screen doesn't turn on. I have checked all the power management settings.
Changed the following in /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="persistent"

Nothing seems to work.
Display manager is SLIM.
Can someone help?
